# 64-bit applications like VLC etc crash if they try to open file dialogs like open file, save file etc

Tags: 64-bit, windows-10

Something's broken ever since the Windows 10 upgrade. No idea what it is. My own 64-bit application included crashes when it tries to access the open file dialog, save dialog etc. These same 64-bit apps work perfectly fine when tested on Windows 7.

I've run sfc /scannow, that didn't solved the problem. Also 32-bit applications have no trouble accessing any of the file dialogs.

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this?

sfc /verifyonly result:

> Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
>
> Beginning verification phase of system scan.
>   Verification 100% complete.
>
> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: Post the result of sfc and dism for us please

Comment: I've posted the sfc result. I don't know how to post the dism one. What do I need to run?

Comment: Anyone here is the dism result: http://pastebin.com/2XAMUazy

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you could try:

1. Check that you don't have any network drives mounted
2. Check that your antivirus supports Windows 10 64-bit. Or temporary turn it off to test if its the problem.
3. Go through what you've installed and see if there's any Shell Extensions that are incompatible.
4. If you have MS Office installed, try to reset the user options and registry settings. See this KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/822005

Comment: Thanks, I checked+did all the things that you said. Nothing has changed.